# comapre two array values equal or not | index to index |

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have a scenario where I want to compare value of array1 and array2

```
echo "${array1[@]}"
```

gives me output1 :   `12.12 10.1`

```
echo "${array2[@]}"
```

gives me output2 :   `12.12 10.1`

**how to compare array1 value with array2 like below**

```
array1[0]=array2[0]
array1[1]=array2[1]

12.12 12.12
10.1 10.1
```

**if matches then display**

**echo** **"success" or "FAIL"**

*Success - when all data in array1 matches with aray2 [index to index]*

*Fail - when index to index value does not match then fail*

Answer (score 1):

You could just compare the arrays as strings:

```bsh
if [[ "${array1[*]}" == "${array2[*]}" ]]; then
  echo success
else
  echo FAIL
fi
```

Note the use of `[*]` not `[@]` -- the first joins the elements into a single string (using the first character of $IFS as the joiner).